# How to run heaptrack on long running server applications

Tags: c++, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, memory-profiling

I have a c++ grpc server image running on GKE kubernetes and I was trying to profile with heaptrack.

in the docker image I installed heaptrack via apt-get, leaving out unrelated stuff the dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as build 
.....
RUN apt-get update && apt install -y software-properties-common && \ 
apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \  
....
heaptrack
... 
ENTRYPOINT ["heaptrack", "./grpc_server"]
```

this creates a docker image which I store on google container registry

I then deploy the image via a yaml file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: grpc-server
        image: grpc_server_container_repo
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "54Gi"
            cpu: "14"
          limits:
            memory: "64Gi"
            cpu: "16"
        ports:
        - name: grpc
          containerPort: 8080
```

after I deployed the image I ssh into the container with the command

```
kubectl exec -it app-6c88bd5854-98dg4 -c grpc-server -- /bin/bash
```

and I saw the file

> heaptrack.grpc_server.1.gz

despite the server still running

I opened this file using heaptrack_gui but it shows total runtime as ~2s, I make a couple request to the server and this file is never updated again. I tried running

```
ps -aux
```

in the container and I can see

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.0   2608  1728 ?        Ss   08:49   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/heaptrack ./grpc_server
root          20  0.4  0.0 1817048 31340 ?       Sl   08:49   0:06 ./grpc_server
root         113  0.0  0.0   4240  3516 pts/0    Ss   09:08   0:00 /bin/bash
root         125  0.0  0.0   6136  2928 pts/0    R+   09:12   0:00 ps -aux
```

seems like I have 2 running instance of the server, one with heaptrack the other don't. I'm not sure what's going on here and was hoping someone can point me some direction to how can I profile a running server on k8s with heaptrack.

Comment: Are you trying to get the file out of the container while it's still running, or are you getting the file from the completed `heaptrack` run?  (How are you starting the container and retrieving the file, and how are you able to make an ssh connection into it?)  This gets substantially harder in Kubernetes FWIW.

Comment: @DavidMaze I updated the question with a bit more detail. I'm not sure how the heaptrack file generated. I assumed it will generate once I stop the server but when I sshed into the machine the server is still running but I already have the file. I don't know how this works and was hoping someone could help me

Comment: from the file name of the heaptrack result it seems to be generated from the pid = 1 process, and somehow I have 2 process running of the server. I'm not sure how that works with a single docker entry point

Comment: In the `ps` output, I'd assume `heaptrack` is pid 1 and it's launching your actual process as a subprocess.  You are not running an ssh daemon that you show here.  My assumption is that you'd need to end the container, let `heaptrack` write its completed file, and extract it from the container (maybe have it write to a bind-mounted directory; this is the part that's hard in Kubernetes).